# WordPress Optimization

Tags: wordpress, optimization

I was wondering how can I optimise my WordPress website without paying many scripts.
Is there a way to optimize my site without putting huge amounts of money into plugins. Thanks for reading my question.

[PageSpeed Result one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR3R1.png)

[PageSpeed Result two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXKBx.png)

Comment: Performance is a big topic for WordPress core recently, and they have a [free plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/performance-lab/) that you can install to test some experiments that they hope to fold into core eventually. Otherwise, your lighthouse score tells you the things to do and includes “learn more” for each. If you aren’t comfortable making those changes, you might need to pay a developer to do that. Otherwise, for not a lot of money, a plugin like WP Rocket is honestly worth it, and they have a money back guarantee

Comment: Also, although the mobile score is very important, unless your site was actually built "mobile first", there’s a good chance that score will be much lower than desktop. I’d focus on getting the desktop score higher first, which is often easier, and the mobile will generally automatically get higher, too.